# help me to find a volume of the ring shaped solid

Tags: integration

A cylindrical drill with radius 5 is used to bore a hole through the center of a sphere of radius 8. Find the volume of the ring shaped solid that remains.

Alright, my thing is that i did not understand how to set the integral

Comment: I don't think you need an integral. Since the hole is drilled through, the height of the cylinder is $\geq8$. So, the area of the sphere is
$$\frac{4}{3}\pi\cdot8^3$$
The area of the cylinder is
$$\geq\pi\cdot5\cdot8$$
The volume remaining is therefore the volume of the sphere minus the are of the cylinder.

Comment: well, your way could be write but there is something wrong with the final answer!

Comment: This does not work.  The cylinder would have a flat top and bottom, but the cylindrical shape drilled out of the sphere would have a curved top and bottom, slightly changing the final answer

Comment: if you mean that the answer should be pi*5*8= 40pi, that also is not right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we must remember how we derive area of a sphere. We start out with $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, or the equation of a circle. Dividing both sides by $r^2$ gives us $\frac{x^2}{r^2} + \frac{y^2}{r^2} = 1$. Subtracting both sides by $\frac{x^2}{r^2}$ gives us $\frac{y^2}{r^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}$. By taking the square root of both sides we have $\frac{y}{r} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}}$ giving us a final equation of $y = r\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}}$. The reason this is important is because we now have an equation for y that is dependent upon x. If you go to desmos and graph this equation, you will get a half circle with no negative y values. This should be clear when looking at the equation.

I will assume we know the area of a circle formula. If you want a proof, go to this website: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/Examples/AreaOfACircle.pdf. Otherwise, I will assume you know it is $\pi r^2 = A$.

By using the disc method, we determine 1. that y is the radius of each disk and 2. that, because $y = r\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}}$, the area of each disk is equal to $\pi(r\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}})^2$. Therefore each disk has a volume of $\pi(\sqrt{r^2}\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2}})$ = $\pi(\sqrt{r^2 - x^2})^2$ = $\pi r^2 - \pi x^2$. Integrating, we have

$\int_{r}^{-r}(\pi r^2 - \pi x^2  ) dx$

$(\pi r^2 x - \frac{\pi x^3}{3} ) $ between -r and r

substituting in $r$ and $-r$ for b and a,  we have

$  (\pi r^2 r  - \frac{\pi (r)^3}{3} )-(\pi r^2 (-r) - \frac{\pi (-r)^3}{3} )$

= $(\pi r^3 - \frac{\pi r^3}{3} ) - (-\pi r^3  + \frac{\pi r^3}{3} ) $

= $(\frac{2 \pi r^3}{3} ) - (\frac{-2\pi r^3}{3} ) $

A = $\frac{4 \pi r^3}{3} $ for a sphere.

Now, let's find the formula for area of the ring outside. This is fairly similar; in order to get the revolution, we will again define a formula for a circle where x is a variable of y and the function passes the variable line test. This is equal to

$y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. I recommend you google this on function and graph it on desmos for some intuition.

For the sake of your problem, let's set r^2 to 64. We now have $y = \sqrt{64 - x^2}$. Now I STRONGLY recommend you graph that function.

Remember, this is just a semicircle with no negative y values. Therefore, to reach the actual area, we must multiply by two. From the problem you gave me, I assume we would use the shell method: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/solid_revolution_topic/solid_of_revolution/v/solid-of-revolution--part-5

This video shows the derivation of the formula for the shell method.

Basically, we will be trying to rotate two times the integral from 5 to 8 for our semicircle. This will give us the ring. Note that $V_r$ represents the area of the ring.

$V_r= 2 \pi \int_{5}^{8} x \sqrt{64 - x^2} dx$. Again, for the derivation of this formula, see the link above.

$V_r= 2 \pi \int_{5}^{8} x \sqrt{64 - x^2} dx$

could do this using u sub but I should be heading off to bed

http://symbolab.com/solver/step_by_step/2%5Cpi%5Cint%5E%7B8%7D_%7B5%7Dx%5Csqrt%7B64%20-%20x%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx%20

Answer (score 3):

If you Google on "hole through a sphere" or "napkin ring formula" you will find that the volume that remains when a sphere is pierced by a cylinder is dependent ***only*** on the height of the "ring".

In this case, the height of the remaining ring is $H$:$$H=2 \times (8^2-5^2)$$
Treat $\frac{H}{2}$ as the radius of a sphere, and the volume of the sphere is the answer.

Some time ago there was a loooong discussion in a math group about this problem: " I drill a 5" long hole centrally through a sphere.  What is the volume of the remaining ring?"

Answer (score 2):

A sphere of radius $8$ is obtained by revolving a circle of radius $8$ about the $x$-axis. If you revolve the region between that circle and the line $y=5$ about the $x$-axis, you obtain the region you're interested in. That means you want to use the washer method, with $f(x)=\sqrt{64-x^2}$ and $g(x)=5$.

The limits of integration are the $x$-values of the intersection points of the graphs of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: so the limits values are 0 to 6 and 0 to 8 ?!

Comment: No, $\sqrt{64-x^2}=5$ leads to $x^2=64-25=39$. Therefore, the limits of integration are from $-\sqrt{39}$ to $\sqrt{39}$

Comment: so i integrate sqrt(64-x^2) from -sqrt39 to sqrt39 and it was a wrong answer!

Comment: No, you use the washer method. That means integrating $\pi[f(x)]^2-\pi[g(x)]^2$ from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: I got this answer which is wrong 54177.66193050882,

Comment: I got that by integrating pi(sqrt(64-x^2)^2-5pi)^2 from -sqrt39 to sqrt39

Comment: Your integrand should be $\pi(39-x^2)$. If you integrate that from $-\sqrt{39}$ to $\sqrt{39}$, you should get a positive number.

Comment: I got this number 324.7398959167169 and it's wrong!!

Comment: I'm getting 1020.2

Comment: yeah your answer is right!!! but please explain to me how did you got that?

Comment: I actually used a computer, and asked it to integrate $\pi(39-x^2)$ from $-\sqrt{39}$ to $\sqrt{39}$. Do you need to know how to obtain that formula, or how to compute the integral, or both?

Comment: ohh I was integrating it without the pi now i know my mistake thank you!